# AngularUI Calendar event source that calls a function on every view switch

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

To demonstrate the problem, I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve. I'm creating a booking system using AngularUI Calendar, and the problem is that the calendar's performance starts to drop very quickly and noticeably when the number of the events increase (100+ events, and the calendar will take minutes to bind data). Due to that I'm trying to fetch data from back-end when view changes by sending AJAX request every time the user change the view (week, month, day, prev, next... etc.) This is when I start to have problems.

As it's been suggested on [AngularUI Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) website that I can use this function: `$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {...}` and add it to the `$scope.eventSources` and it will be called on every view switch. I added the `$scope.eventsF` to my `$scope.eventSources` but it's never updated.

Here is the sample (fetching all data, and it's working):

```
$scope.mainEvents = []; //To initiate the event source
Event.getEvents().then(function (events) { // Event is a factory
  if (events) { //Checking if I have events
    // If I try: $scope.mainEvents = events; the $scope.eventSources won't update
    angular.forEach(events, function(value) {
      this.push(value);
    }, $scope.mainEvents);
  } else {
    // Tell the user no events to render...
  }
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents];
```

Now I changed `Event.getEvents()` to take two parameters as start date and end date of the view, send them to the back-end, and retrieve data as json again (worked fine, I consoled that out).

Here is the code (I tried two ways): Events are rendering, but `$scope.eventSources` is not updating in both of them.

First:

```
$scope.mainEvents = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
  var s = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      e = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  Event.getEvents(s, e).then(function (events) {
    $scope.mainEvents = []; //even tried $scope.eventSources.mainEvents
    if (events) {
      angular.forEach(events, function (value) {
        this.push(value);
      }, $scope.mainEvents); //event tried $scope.eventSources.mainEvents
      callback($scope.mainEvents);
    }
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents];
```

Second:

```
$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
  var s = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      e = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  Event.getEvents(s, e).then(function (events) {
    $scope.mainEvents = [];
    if (events) {
      angular.forEach(events, function (value) {
        this.push(value);
      }, $scope.mainEvents);
      callback($scope.mainEvents);
    }
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents, $scope.eventsF];
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: If I understood you correctly - adding 100 events, when only say 10 are displayed causes problems? That's a bit strange...

Comment: Nope, you missed the AngularUI calendar main purpose, which is keep watching events for change (data binding). What I meant is that when the `$scope.eventSources` contains 100 events (whether they have been added or modified), the performance decrease, again because `$scope` is watching these events for changes (change in title, start time, end time... etc)

Comment: If you try to add more than 100 events to the sample on the angularUiCalendar vendor's site. Doe's it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. I didn't quite get why I have to do it this way, but I managed to make it work. I had remove the events from the `$scope.mainEvents` array, one by one (I think in the AngularUI Calendar, they are using `$watch` for every single event), then add the new events from promise to the `$scope.mainEvents` also one by one. **DO NOT** use the `callback()` function, as the `$scope` will be updated (`$watch` will take care of the rendering), so the `callback()` will render the event again so you will end up with each event rendered twice.
Here is the final code:

```
$scope.mainEvents = [];
$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
  //moment.js objects
  var s = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      e = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  Event.getEvents(s, e).then(function (events) {
    //emptying the array
    $scope.mainEvents.splice(0, $scope.mainEvents.length);

    //add the retrieved events
    angular.forEach(events, function (value) {
        this.push(value);
      }, $scope.mainEvents);
  }, function (error) {
    //promise error logic
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is by re-assigning event sources to `$scope.eventSources` at the end of `$scope.eventsF`. Code below is based on your second option. Cheers.

```
$scope.mainEvents = [];
$scope.draftEvents = [];
$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var s = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    e = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    Event.getEvents(s, e).then(function (events) {
        $scope.mainEvents = [];
        if (events) {
            angular.forEach(events, function (value) {
                this.push(value);
            }, $scope.mainEvents);
            // Re-assign event sources
            $scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents, $scope.eventsF];
            // Assume that 'events' is an array with 5 elements.
            // console.log($scope.eventSources) will produce :
            // Array [ Array[5], Array[0], app</$scope.eventsF() ]

            callback($scope.mainEvents);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents, $scope.eventsF];
// console.log($scope.eventSources) will produce :
// Array [ Array[0], Array[0], app</$scope.eventsF() ]
```

#### Edit

I've updated the code above to show at which part I tested the `$scope.eventSources`. Can you please show at which part of the sample code you would like the `$scope.eventSources` get updated ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify at which part I tested the `$scope.eventSources`. Can you show me at which part of the code you would like to test `$scope.eventSources`? Cheers.

Comment: I'm using `ngInspector`, but you can bind `$scope.eventSources` in the HTML, to make sure that it's updated (I know it's not the best approach for testing, but it works just fine for debugging), like this `{{eventSources | json}}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is caused by Javascript's variable scope. You were referencing to `$scope.eventSources` in different scope than `$scope.eventSources` in you controller. Perhaps `$scope.eventSources` get copied somewhere in [AngularUI Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/).

You could access `$scope.eventSources` in your controller by simply create a variable that holds a reference to the variable.

```
// Create a variable that holds reference to controller's $scope
var ctrlScope = $scope;

$scope.mainEvents = [];
$scope.draftEvents = [];
$scope.eventsF = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var s = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    e = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    Event.getEvents(s, e).then(function (events) {
        if (events) {
            angular.forEach(events, function (value) {
                this.push(value);
            }, $scope.mainEvents);
            // Test
            console.log(ctrlScope.eventSources);

            callback($scope.mainEvents);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.mainEvents, $scope.draftEvents, $scope.eventsF];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I don't think that's the problem (the `$scope.eventSources` is accessible and the whole logic depends on that). As I mentioned in the question, the `callback` method is basically rendering the events on the calendar, but not updating the `$scope.mainEvents`.